# sftp "remote open failure"

Tags: linux, sftp, file-transfer

I sftp'ed into my linux server from my macbook. I have never had issues transferring files through sftp until now.

I am getting the following error when I try to `put` something on my linux server

```
sftp> put test.cpp
Uploading test.cpp to /home/mylin/test.cpp
remote open("/home/mylin/test.cpp"): Failure
```

When I try to `get` something, it works. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does `test.cpp` already exist on your Linux server? If so, do you have write permissions to it?

Comment: This is a failure by the `sftp` client to get a handle on the SSH connection for doing the upload (according to the `sftp` [source code](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/src/usr.bin/ssh/sftp-client.c?rev=1.134&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup)). Is the error persistent (i.e. does it _always_ occur, or was it only once)? Does it occur only for the `put` command? Can you reproduce it with `sftp -v` and post the output?

Comment: @Peschke 
I just figured out the issue. I ran out of disk space on my linux server hah. I only just found out when I tried to create a directory.

Comment: @Kusalananda I just found out that I ran out of disk space on my linux server.

Answer (score 3):

I faced this issue too and turned out the remote directory was 100 %. Please check the remote server directory where you are pushing the file and clear the space if it is 100 % full.

Comment: This is indeed what the OP [mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/534654/sftp-remote-open-failure#comment990654_534654). But you get the kudos for taking the time to write it up as an answer - thank you.